# how to pass reference to 2D array as parameter

Tags: c, pointers

I have code similar to the following which does not work and keeps throwing pointer errors. how should I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
           {1, 4, 3, 2},
           {9, 8, 7, 6}};

int main()
{
  do_something_to_matrix(get_matrix());
}

get_matrix()
{
   return &mat;
}

do_something_to_matrix(int matrix[][4])
{
  //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: arrays are always passed by reference in c. use `int *matrix` to get it. you must de-reference it to change it.

Answer (score 1):

One sample

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mat[][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {1, 4, 3, 2},
    {9, 8, 7, 6}
};

void do_something_to_matrix(int matrix[][4]);
int (*get_matrix(void))[4];

int main(void){
    do_something_to_matrix(get_matrix());
    return 0;
}

int (*get_matrix(void))[4]{
    return mat;
}

void do_something_to_matrix(int matrix[][4]){
    //do some stuff
    printf("%d\n", matrix[2][1]);//8
}
```