# how to get pointer to point to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is wrong with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int array = {{1, 2, 3},
             {4, 5, 6}, 
             {7, 8, 9}};

int (*get_matrix(void))[4]
{
  return array;
}

int main()
{
  int* anarray[4] = get_matrix();
}
```

this gives me the following error:
 error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass reference to 2D array as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288765/how-to-pass-reference-to-2d-array-as-parameter)

Comment: This question was already answered with a code sample. Read those answers, don't just post almost the same thing on a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the array size as well as the dimensions!

try this:

```
int array[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3},
                   {4, 5, 6}, 
                   {7, 8, 9}};
```

Also you this

```
int* anarray = get_matrix();
```

instead of your old code!